# Calculating Change in Attributes from two different years on two overlaid maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, change-detection

I am looking at comparing wetlands gains and losses along a certain area. I have downloaded maps from NLCD over multiple years and am struggling on how to compare them on ArcGIS.

The two aspects that I am trying to compare are listed in the attributes tables of two datasets. I tried using an intersect function to perform the task but that datasets didn't work as a possible input.

Is there a way that I can compare these data sets to create a new layer that will show the changes between them?

Comment: Google "arcgis spaghetti meatballs" for a blog on polygon/polygon comparison usung label points.

Comment: Nice blog. An alternate approach is to convert features to raster and use raster math to get the results you want. Definitely fewer steps...